# TFS 2015 slow to populate Incoming Requests after update

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

My organisation recently applied an update to TFS 2015 (14.102.25423.0 according to the 'About' page of the web interface) that resulted in the 'My Work' tab in Visual Studio 2015 taking up to one minute to populate. I played around with the queries and managed to narrow the problem down to population of the 'Incoming Requests' section of that tab. Under the hood, this is executing the following WIQL query.

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.Links.LinkType], [System.Title], [System.State], [System.Reason], [System.AssignedTo] 
FROM WorkItemLinks 
WHERE (Source.[System.TeamProject] = @project and Source.[System.WorkItemType] in group 'Microsoft.CodeReviewRequestCategory' and Source.[System.AssignedTo] &lt;&gt; @me and Source.[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateCode] &lt;&gt; '1')
    and ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') 
    and (Target.[System.WorkItemType] in group 'Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory' and (Target.[System.AssignedTo] = @me or Target.[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy] = @me) and Target.[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateCode] &lt;&gt; '2') 
ORDER BY [System.CreatedDate] desc, [System.Id] mode(MustContain)
```

- I've reproduced the slowness using the TFS REST API described in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql (passing the WIQL query above in the body of the POST request).
- The following code review selectors are *slow* to populate: **My Code Reviews & Requests**, **Incoming Requests**.
- The following code review selectors are *fast* to populate: **My Code Reviews**, **Recently Finished**, **Recently Closed**.
- The problem is occurring for all users, not just my user.
- No one on the team has more than a few code reviews open at any one time.
- The problem started occurring practically overnight i.e. on Friday the queries were completing in a second or so, on Monday the queries were taking up to a minute.
- Our TFS environment is hosted on Windows Server 2012 (non-R2).
- Our TFS environment is backed by SQL Server 2012, SP3 (11.0.6020).
- The upgrade to TFS2015.3 was completed as per Microsoft instructions and no issues were encountered and there are no messages in the logs to indicate anything is wrong.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what might be causing this slowness and what can be checked in order to narrow the performance problem down further?

Comment: What verion of SQL Server are you running? There used to be some known issues with Identity fields in TFS depending on the compat level SQL was running in.

Comment: @nschonni, we're running SQL Server 2012, SP3. I'm guessing that's modern enough not to result in obscure Identity field issues?

Comment: Funnily enough 2012 is old enough that it shouldn't hit the bug I was thinking of https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2953452. The problems actually occur if you're running 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here... My organisation ended up escalating this through Microsoft and eventually found that there was an issue with out of date statistics causing bad query plan generation. The query that was used to retrieve code review details was taking more than 60 seconds each time it was run.

The queries below will most likely make a significant different to performance if you encounter the same problem.

```
use <collection db name>;
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCoreLatest] WITH FULLSCAN

use <collection db name>;
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[tbl_WorkItemCustomLatest] WITH FULLSCAN
```

For reference, there's a duplicate of my original post on Microsoft Connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/3107261. The comments from Microsoft in this post indicate a number of people were seeing similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The Team Explorer in Visual Studio provides **a dropdown selector** for specifying **which state of code reviews one wants to list**. The available choices are:

```
My Code Reviews and Requests (open)
My Code Reviews (open/mine)
Incoming Requests (open/others)
Recently Closed (closed)
Recently Finished (finished)
```

( *Annotated each entry above with the state and ownership for clarity.*)

According to the description of your performance issue, since this is occurring for all users, seems there are a large number of code reviews in your team. When you open the *My work* tab , the loading of the various code reviews cause a performance issue.

For this situation, you can try this workaroud: switch over to ***my code reviews***   in that Team Explorer drop down selector. After this, please double check whether the issue is gone or still exist.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I've updated the question with more detail. The 'My Code Reviews and Requests' and 'Incoming Requests' selectors are slow; the others are fast. Unfortunately we use this tab to identify incoming requests so simply using the fast selectors isn't an option. The problem started happening overnight leading me to believe that build up of code review data isn't the problem e.g. it's like the update pulled an index of a critical database table for instance.

Comment: Looks logical, however if there's something wrong with TFS database after the update. The performance issue should be reflected not only in such a place. Did you get any other  significant performance issues such as connect to TFS, download files from TFS?

Comment: First, please make sure your TFS admin has finished all configurations after update. And check the update logs in TFS Server whether there is some useful info.You can also use [/Log (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) to track  all activity log file of VS for troubleshooting.

Comment: Another way is since you have mentioned, they are just some work item query, You can also query Work Items **using SQL on the Relational Warehouse** follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse/) to judge if there is something wrong in the warehouse.

Comment: Thanks again Patrick, I've updated the question with more details and will probably focus any further diagnostics on the backing SQL database using a SQL profiler or 'long running query' analysis. The logs (client and server-side) aren't showing any problems.